# Simple button code using interface

Tags: java, swing, button

I'll write the code first and ask my question below

Below is my main class

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runApp();
        }

    });
}

public static void runApp() {
    Model model = new Model();
    View view = new View(model);

    Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);

    view.setLoginListener(controller);
}

}
```

Below is my another class

```
public class LoginFormEvent {
private String name;
private String password;

public LoginFormEvent(String name, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Below is my controller class

```
public class Controller implements LoginListener {
private View view;
private Model model;

public Controller(View view, Model model) {
    this.view = view;
    this.model = model;
}

@Override
public void loginPerformed(LoginFormEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Login event received: " + event.getName() + "; " + event.getPassword());

}


}
```

Below is my LoginListener interface

```
public interface LoginListener {
public void loginPerformed(LoginFormEvent event);
}
```

Lastly below is my view class which I have just deleted the JFrame code for simplicity.

```
public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private Model model;
private JButton okButton;
private JTextField nameField;
private JPasswordField passField;

private LoginListener loginListener;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String password = new String(passField.getPassword());
    String name = nameField.getText();

    fireLoginEvent(new LoginFormEvent(name, password));
}

public void setLoginListener(LoginListener loginListener) {
    this.loginListener = loginListener;
}

public void fireLoginEvent(LoginFormEvent event) {
    if(loginListener != null) {
        loginListener.loginPerformed(event);
    }
}

}
```

It is a standard button coordinating code so you guys probably won't even need to read my code to answer my question.

So I know how to write this code and this is how I write it when I want a button to do call some action. But when I try to get my logic around it to understand 'why' it works, I get very confused.

so when I call `view.setLoginListener(controller)` I'm obviously expecting some kind of LoginFormEvent.

Then when I click the button, in the `view` class, `new LoginFormEvent` is constructed.

But then how is the constructed `LoginFormEvent` within the view class be set as the parameter of expected `LoginFormEvent` in controller class when there's not really any connection between the two classes except that I have defined `view.setLoginListener(controller)` in the Application class. This just makes setLoginListener of particular instance of view to expect some kind of LoginListener, meaning it doesn't really have to be the one that I set up in the view class upon a click of a button? But obviously it does have to be because that's how the code is run. but why?

Comment: You're going to have to edit that last paragraph to make it comprehensible. Right now it is a giant run-on sentence that I can't make any sense of.

Comment: Sorry I mightve been too frustrated my logic does it make better sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the flow as below

Lets start with`Application.java`. lets see the method  `runApp()`. It does below things.

1. Objects of `View.java` and `Controller.java` are created.
2. `Controller.java` `implements` `LoginListener.java`
   view.setLoginListener(controller); // this sets the object of
   Controller.java in the object of View.java, both these objects are
   same as created in step-1.

Now lets move to `View.java`

It has a field `private LoginListener loginListener;` and method `public void setLoginListener(LoginListener loginListener)`. This method sets the field `loginListener` As we see above in step 2 `loginListener` refers to the same object of Controller.java created in step 1 above.

Now lets move to `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` defined in `View.java`.

It calls `fireLoginEvent(new LoginFormEvent(name, password));` See now Object of `LoginFormEvent.java` is created and it is passed as a parameter to the method `fireLoginEvent(LoginFormEvent event)`.

Now moving to `public void fireLoginEvent(LoginFormEvent event)`

It has code : `loginListener.loginPerformed(event);`. From above we know `loginListener` refers to the **one and only object** of `Controller.java` 
method `public void loginPerformed(LoginFormEvent event)` on that very object of Controller.java is called and same object of (**again one and only one**) `LoginEvent.java` is passed as parameter.

> For such type of scenarios, I would recommend you to note the objects created of each type and connect the flow of calls. Hope above helps you understand the code.

Comment: Hey this is really great but is there such thing as setting an object in another object by passing it into a parameter when it was already pre defined in the whole class `application`?

Comment: Also, what I am also curious abt is that the moment LoginListener is set up in setLoginListener, it is obviously already read by compiler already. But then when buttons clicked, it is somehow read again? As if setting this.loginListener= loginListener in view class sets its parameter to be equal to the instance of loginListener in View class instead of the parameter setting the instance of loginListener to be equal to the parameter? Kinda reversed? Or can it work reversed as well

Comment: Application.java creates the Objects of Model.java, View.java and Controller.java. In a note book, create 3 circles for each of these objects. We have 3 Objects because we created 3 objects using new keyword. Now we need 3 references, named model, view and controllers. Write these 3 names and point  1 each to a circle. Now lets see the relationship, These are referenced by local variables. Objects of Model.java and View.java are passed to the object of Controller.java in its constructor. Object of Controller.java is set in Object of View.java using a setter method. Draw lines for these n' see.

Comment: While compile time only the grammar (syntax) is checked. Only while run time objects are created in Heap and from stack and heap references refer to the other objects and we have the relationship between the objects.

Comment: Ohhh okay thank you so much for this ! I lack one point to be able to promote ur answer though sorry...